# Adding/delegating/binding a change event to Chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, jquery-chosen

I am using a plugin for my selectors. It is called [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). I am trying to add a listener to any of the following but I feel that the plugin is preventing anything from happening. Ideally I wanted to add an event so that everytime someone adds a "tag" to a multiple select group a method gets called. However this is proving to be more difficult then it should be. So far I have have tried the following:

```
//detect when input field changes
$(".chzn-choices").find("input").change(function () { alert("lol I worked"); });

//detect when option is clicked (I dont think this works as a click event is already     binded to these and something is preventing the default
$(".chzn-drop").delegate("li", "click", function () { alert("clicked"); });
```

Anyone have any ideas what I could try here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Form Field Change

When working with form fields, you often want to perform some behavior after a value has been selected or deselected. Whenever a user selects a field in Chosen, it triggers a "change" event* on the original form field. That let's you do something like this:

```
$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );
```